# Joomla main menu not showing all K2 Product Categories

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-k2

I am using K2 component to showcase my products. I have created a menu item in my main menu for showing all my product categories (without sub categories) in a catalog style (To do this I went to- menu item> K2>Item Listing>Categories). I have created three product categories and six product items, but when I click on the menu I created it just shows only one category.

I want to display all the categories in a catalog style (No sub categories or items) when clicked on the menu. For example: http://demo.getk2.org/en/catalog

Would you please kindly tell me how to do this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the parameters for how K2 categories display in:

```
K2 > Categories > [Your Main Category] > Category View Options > Sub-category handling
```

(Change in the Parameters... you can also use the 'Inherit parameter options from category' to set other categories to follow the same format once you get it set up how you want)